# Should I add taxpayer identification number in invoice?

Tags: invoices

I am in EU and I have a client in US.

Should I add my VAT id/taxpayer identification number in the invoice?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

Just like your [business] name, address, phone number, email address.... Any specific information regarding taxes such as an EID, TaxID, VAT ID should *always* be present on invoices, even *if* the payee does not necessarily need that information for a particular invoice.

Comment: It is normal if you are a Limited company to include Company Incorporation number and VAT number if registered, even if client is in a different company law and tax jurisdiction.